# How to redirect a route in Rails 4 to a file inside the public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an App (Rails 4 + Angular) which the admin area will be an Angular app. I'm following (loosely) [this](http://www.angularonrails.com/how-to-wire-up-ruby-on-rails-and-angularjs-as-a-single-page-application-gulp-version/) tutorial.

I've created a client directory in the root directory (I'm using a Gulp generator) so I can develop, unit test the applications separately but when deploying, both apps will work together, the Rails app will provide the API plus traditional routes in a Rails app and the Angular app will be an admin interface to create content and manage a series of services (business logic).

I'd like to compile the Angular app to the public folder and create a route in Rails `/admin` that will redirect to the public folder. How can I do this in Rails 4?

Comment: You could probably look at [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/) on how to do it. I did this quite recently, but I kept the API and the Angular app in two separate projects. You might also want to try that approach.

Comment: But in that tutorial it added the angular app as a normal route in Rails, which is fine if your app is relatively small and/or you're not doing unit testing. Keeping it separate gives you more flexibility (specially in a bigger, more complex app). I'm also considering keep it separate but I'd keep it together.